# Cannot make bash script work from cloud-init

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Obviously I am doing something wrong here.

Cloud init script `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

```
...
runcmd:
 - [ sh, /opt/cloud-init-scripts/whatever.sh ]
```

The script `/opt/cloud-init-scripts/whatever.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
...
. /home/ubuntu/third-party/script.sh --silent
```

Third party script `/home/ubuntu/third-party/script.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function some_function() {
...
```

Error I am getting in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

```
/opt/cloud-init-scripts/whatever.sh: 3: /home/ubuntu/third-party/script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I must be missing something obvious here. I tried using `source`, `.` and `sh` when calling the third party script, tried changing shebangs everywhere but no success.

If I run the same command from command line it works.

Comment: As soon as I wrote it it downed on me (of course!) I also had some permissions problems there but unrelated to this question. If you want to write above as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified `sh` shell under `runcmd`, but have she-bang set to `bash`. The latter does not matter because if you run as `sh /opt/cloud-init-scripts/whatever.sh` it will be run with sh shell. I guess you are probably using a non `POSIX` shell feature which is incompatible with the `sh` shell.

Or alternatively if your intention is to run the script in `bash` shell, change the `runCmd` in `cloud-init` script to

```
runcmd:
 - [ bash, /opt/cloud-init-scripts/whatever.sh ]
```

Comment: Just FYI I ended up doing: `- [ /opt/cloud-init-scrips/whatever.sh ]` without specifying what command to use