# How to run custom install commands/scripts with cloudinit

Tags: bash, yaml, cloud-init, multipass

I am running `multipass` with `cloudinit` and I have a bash script which I need to run after the VMs have been deployed once but for each user account. It has simple commands in it mostly for customising vim and `bash.rc`. How can I achieve this?

I tried playing around with [runcmd feature of cloudinit](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html) but it is [a bit problematic](https://gist.github.com/aw/40623531057636dd858a9bf0f67234e8) and even simple commands like the below don't output anything.

```
package_update: true                                                                                                                                                                                  
 package_upgrade: true                                                       
 packages:                                                                   
   - git                                                                     
   - openssh-server                                                          
   - zip                                                                     
   - tree                                                                    
   - vim                                                                     
   - htop                                                                    
   - net-tools                                                               
   - sysstat                                                                 
   - locate                                                                  
 cloud_config_modules:                                                       
   - runcmd                                                                  
 cloud_final_modules:                                                        
   - scripts-user                                                            
 runcmd:                                                                     
   - [ ls, -l, / ]                                                           
   - [ sh, -xc, "echo $(date) ': hello world!'" ]                            
   - [ bash, -c, echo "=========hello world'=========" >>foo.bar]            
 users:                                                                      
   - name: aryan                                                             
     lock_passwd: true                                                       
     sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL                                            
     shell: /bin/bash                                                        
     ssh_authorized_keys:                                                    
       - ...
```

Comment: There is a potentially related question, but it has no answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297120/cannot-make-bash-script-work-from-cloud-init

Answer (score 0):

That gist is technically correct, but it's a little misleading. `runcmd` in `cloud_config_modules` and `scripts-user` in `cloud_final_modules` will already be specified by default in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`, so unless you want to explicitly turn off the other modules in use by cloud-init (you don't want to do this unless you have a good reason to), you don't need to specify `cloud_config_modules` or `cloud_final_modules` in your cloud-config.

Did you include `#cloud-config` at the top of your userdata script? If not, your cloud config is invalid. If you did include it, these runcmds will all work. The output of `ls` and the date/echo will be in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` and `foo.bar` will be in `/`. If not, there's something else wrong in your cloud config, or something that prevented cloud-init from initializing completely.

On your launched instance, you can run `cloud-init status --long` to see if cloud-init succeeded or failed. You can also check `/var/log/cloud-init.log` for `Traceback` or `WARN` to get an idea of what failed. Searching for `rumcmd` or `scripts-user` should tell you if those commands ran and what was written out where.

Comment: What about longer scripts (eg. 100+ lines), should they be modified and inserted into the `cloudinit.yaml` file or is there a way to pass a bash script to be run for each account as that user?

Comment: You can insert them into cloudinit.yaml if you'd like. If you just want to use a script (and not cloud-config), any script that starts with '#!' can be used as userdata. If you want both the cloud-config and a separate user script, that involves creating a mime multi part archive. That is slightly more complicated, but cloud-init provides a helper to make it easier. See https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#mime-multi-part-archive

Comment: I guess I am having some more basic issues like: (1) cloud-init vs cloud-config (I think the latter is a cofig file used by the former service, (2) where do I put my bash script (eg. `foo.sh`), (3) how do I tell cloud-init/cloud config to call that script?

Comment: Your (1) is correct. Cloud-init is a service that runs on boot. You are trying to pass "user data" which can be a cloud config, a script, a mime archive, or a few other things listed in the previous URL I linked to. The types of user data are differentiated by a comment at the top of the file. "#cloud-config" means cloud config, "#!" means script, and so on. Since you're running on multipass, if you just want to run a script, you can save it anywhere and have cloud-init use it with `multipass launch <type> --name <name> --cloud-init <path/to/foo.sh>`

Comment: That is how I am calling multipass right now (`multipass launch --name foo --cloud-init foo.yaml`) but `foo.yaml` creates the VM with all the user accounts, what if I also need to run a script on each account created, how do I do that? Right now I am using `SSH`

Comment: There is no built in mechanism to run something per account. Cloud-init runs as root, so you'd have to script that part yourself into a single script. If you want your user data to a combination of the cloud config and a script, you'd need to generate a MIME multi-part file as your user data: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#helper-subcommand-to-generate-mime-messages

Comment: Check my new project for reference. I have done same in my project using a bash script. You can also do it with a makefile. https://github.com/nikhiljohn10/step-ca-tutorials